# animating constraints out of screen on all devices

Tags: ios, animation, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I'm animating constraints so that view goes out of screen. I set the constraints like this:

```
        upperLeadingConstraint.constant = -344
        upperTrailingConstraint.constant = 356
```

**upperLeadingConstraint** sets the distance to left edge of the screen, **upperTrailingConstraint** sets the distance to right edge of the screen.

Is this working on universal displays like iphone6+ ? Or should I make the constants a little bigger just to be safe? Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you set these constraints, I mean to what elements. To get the answer on your question you must provide more details or you can calculate the position of the element on other devices by your own.

Comment: @krompir2 you can use something like upperLeadingConstraint.constant =  -self.view.frame.size.width;     upperTrailingConstraint.constant = self.view.frame.size.width. This will be work if view have the same width as the self.view. If its located with some offsets you must add them to new values. For example upperLeadingConstraint.constant =  -self.view.frame.size.width -/+ 10 (depends on what layout you have). The same with second. Hope it will helps